# Metadata Extension missing in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, sapui5, abap, sap-fiori

I am trying to create a Metadata Extension for my CDS View in Eclipse IDE 2021-06. I already installed all ABAP software from https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/latest. Still I am not able to create a Metadata Extension, because the button just doesn't exist.

So when I go to "Core Data Services" in my project und click on "New", I am only able to select "Access Control" and "Data Definition". There is no button with "Metadata Extension".

What is more, Eclipse doesn't recognize the annotation `@Metadata.allowExtensions: true` in my CDS view. The `allowExtensions` is colored red.

I guess I need to install some additional extensions or libraries for this, but there just is no documentation about this topic on the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kindly check your NW Version. Support for ME View might start from a specific version.

Comment: Exactly, in my version (750) this option is not available. Gonna need to find a workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing the same problem:
You can simply add the annotations needed directly to the CDS View Data Definition. No need for an external Metadata Extension file.